# eBay Autofill using native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, browser-automation

I’m trying to input some information to eBay using the dev console and I thought it would be super simple with something like this:

`document.querySelector(“.exampleInput).value = “exampleText”`

But as I tried that the actual input box didn’t change, the value also didn’t change so I tried using .innerText, as well as changing the actual html of the input on the form with (.innerHTML) but all of these methods failed.

I looked into the network tab to see what was going on and it seems like eBay is using some sort of data collection system which tracks your movement to see if you are actually typing or not So I was hoping to see if anyone could figure out a way to input text into the form fields with native js or even jQuery.

Comment: For form inputs use the value property

Comment: I've just added text to eBay search with this code 
  `document.querySelector('.ui-autocomplete-input').value = 'exampleText'`
I believe you used wrong selector

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).